# Need Ubuntu driver for CH342 uart?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, ham-radio

The data interface DE-19 for my G90 Ham Radio transceiver, both from Xiegu requires me to install "CH342 port driver."  The company tech support site (http://www.cqxiegu.com/) offers only a Windows version of this driver.  I've asked them about an Ubuntu driver.  Not surprisingly, they don't have one.  So I need to extend my quest here since I'm trying to test this equipment for a trip in just five weeks to the US Mainland (from Hawaii), my first in a long time.  (Specific sob story left out.)
Mahalo.

Comment: Have you tried [this open source driver](https://github.com/juliagoda/CH341SER)? They even have [Ubuntu-specific instructions](https://github.com/juliagoda/CH341SER/blob/master/ubuntu.md). From what I can see, the CH342 is not *that* different from the 340 and 341, which both use the same driver 

Comment: This looks promising matigo.  Thank you!  I'm not sure I'm up to doing the compilation etc .... its been so long and I'm running out of time.  Spotty and rusty skill set here.  Right now I'm making sure that the device itself works under Windows and having trouble.  Once I know the interface device is working, I'll be back here to start on the Ubuntu solution.

Comment: I finally confirmed the equipment itself is working now I can get serous about getting it working under Ubuntu!  For that I'm asking for more help on a current CH34x driver for Ubuntu as I don't understand enough to follow the lead matigo provided.

Comment: Tried above.  Added git successfully.  Downloaded source.  Got good build but on then this error:    ~/CH341SER$ make load
modprobe usbserial
insmod ch34x.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ch34x.ko: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:12: load] Error 1